# Gate of a transistor and mosfet damaged

Tags: transistors, mosfet, damage

In my schematic, I found that the base of transistor Q7 (2n2222) was damaged. I tried to replace it with a BS170 MOSFET, and the same thing happened where the gate was damaged.

The microcontroller has a simple operation where it activates Q7 with a cycle of 0.8 seconds on, 0.2 seconds off, driving 24 MOSFETs in parallel. The MOSFET controls an external source of 100V, 100A.

There's also an overcurrent protection circuit that is not pictured. When overcurrent is detected, a signal is sent to my microcontroller and this cause Q9 to be activated.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Hi Juan, welcome and thank you for your question. Can you tell us more about how the transistors were damaged? Did they become open circuits or short circuits? Was the gate/base shorted to the source/emitter? Did the transistors physically overheat and give off smoke?

Comment: Does each MOSFET have its own gate resistor?  What is the switching frequency?

Comment: Is D6 undamaged? Can you verify that with a multimeter?

Comment: If it's an inductive load and with a current draw of 100A a flyback diode may be required.

Comment: @CoreyF true, but unless both a FET and D6 are damaged by the unclamped inductive load, Q7 should be fine.  So I'm interested to see if D6 failed open.  (Which seems unlikely, but I don't see anything else obvious in the schematic which would cause an issue.)

Comment: Something is wrong with how the main load is connected, the 100-V power is floating, and who knows what kind of coupling to system ground does it have.

Comment: Andrey Akhmetov : Yes, in transistor become short circuits between base and emitter, and in mosfet short circuit between gate and source, also open circuit at the diode of the mosfet. Did not overheat.

Comment: user28910 : Yes, each mosfet have its own gate resistor. The frequency it`s very slow, 1Hz approximately. Thanks

Comment: D6 it`s fine, no problem whit the diode. I thik that the problems started when added the circuit of Q9 and Q8. I made a lot of measurement whit oscilloscope and i cant´t see any strange thing or spike. I dont know what is the problem. Thank a lot to everyone